# Php parse error, help me fix the mistake

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error

there is a mistake in this code. What's the correct code?

```
<?php
$guide = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpb_in_onda', TRUE);
if($guide){
?>
<div>
<?php echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($guide));?>
</div>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in CODE on line 7

Comment: There is at least a closing `}` missing at the end.

Comment: At least give us the error message.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in CODE on line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either user `if:else:endif;` syntax:

```
<?php
$guide = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpb_in_onda', TRUE);
if($guide):
?>
<div><?php echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($guide));?></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

or what you are doing, but you need the closing if brace `}`:

```
<?php
$guide = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpb_in_onda', TRUE);
if($guide){
?>
<div><?php echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($guide));?></div>
<?}; // this is missing in your code ?>
```

or you can echo out the HTML as well:

```
<?php
$guide = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpb_in_onda', TRUE);
if($guide){
    echo '<div>' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($guide)) . '</div>';
}; 
?>
```

Comment: The 2° code works but the last gives me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in CODE on line 4. The second code is correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't end your if tag. Next to that it isn't really clean to break out of PHP for some HTML coding, you'd rather use the "echo" command in PHP.

Comment: Do I have to add <?php endif; ?> ? Sorry but I don't know PHP

Comment: @ankloop , depends on your which syntax you want to use. see my answer